# How can I serialize and deserialize this class in C# with Json.Net?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I want to serialize and deserialize the following class:

```
public class SettingsToSyncModel
{
    public SettingsToSyncModel()
    {
        this.DatabasesToSync = new List<DatabasesToSyncModel>();
        this.TablesToSync = new List<TablesToSyncModel>();
    }

    public SettingsToSyncModel(IList<DatabasesToSyncModel> databases, IList<TablesToSyncModel> tables)
    {
        this.DatabasesToSync = new List<DatabasesToSyncModel>();
        this.TablesToSync = new List<TablesToSyncModel>();
        if (databases.Any()) DatabasesToSync = databases;
        if (tables.Any()) TablesToSync = tables;
    }
    [JsonProperty("databasesToSync")]
    public IList<DatabasesToSyncModel> DatabasesToSync { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tablesToSync")]
    public IList<TablesToSyncModel> TablesToSync { get; set; }
}

public class DatabasesToSyncModel
{
    public DatabasesToSyncModel() { }

    public DatabasesToSyncModel(int databaseId, string databaseName, string databaseConnection)
    {
        this.DatabaseId = databaseId;
        this.DatabaseName = databaseName;
        this.DatabaseConnection = databaseConnection;
    }
    [JsonProperty("database_id")]
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("database_name")]
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("database_connection")]
    public string DatabaseConnection { get; set; }
}

public class TablesToSyncModel
{
    public TablesToSyncModel() { }


    public TablesToSyncModel(int tableId, string tableName, int databaseId)
    {
        this.TableId = tableId;
        this.TableName = tableName;
        this.DatabaseId = databaseId;
    }

    [JsonProperty("table_id")]
    public int TableId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("table_name")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("database_id")]
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize it like this:

```
var jsonSettings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settingsToSync);
```

I obtain a string like this:

```
"{\"databasesToSync\":[{\"database_id\":1,\"database_name\":\"prova\",\"database_connection\":\"test_connection_prova\"},{\"database_id\":3,\"database_name\":\"prova2\",\"database_connection\":\"test_connection_prova2\"}],\"tablesToSync\":[{\"table_id\":1,\"table_name\":\"contatti\",\"database_id\":1},{\"table_id\":2,\"table_name\":\"produzione\",\"database_id\":1},{\"table_id\":3,\"table_name\":\"lavorazioni\",\"database_id\":3},{\"table_id\":4,\"table_name\":\"ordini\",\"database_id\":3}]}"
```

I cannot deserialize it with the same class

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsToSyncModel>(jsonResponse);
```

Stack Trace:

```
in Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   in Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   in Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
```

Exception Error:

```
Error converting value to type 'SettingsToSyncModel'
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: You need to show the error as well

Comment: Can you share `jsonResponse` string value?

Comment: There must be something else going on. I copied and pasted your code into a simple console application and it deserialised perfectly fine when I ran it.